# While practicing streamBuilder , an Error appeared

Tags: flutter, dart

i tried firestore

I wrapped the code in a streambuilder to give the Raised Button a doc

but I got the error

type `'MappedListIterable<DocumentSnapshot, Widget>'` is not a subtype of type 'List'

I want the textformfield of the updatepage not to be blank, but to load the stored data.

How can I solve this?

I dont Know what should i do

This is the UPDATE page of the CRUD.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class Update extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _UpdateState createState() => _UpdateState();
}

class _UpdateState extends State<Update> {
  GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  TextEditingController _titleController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _descController = TextEditingController();
  final db = Firestore.instance;
  DocumentSnapshot _currentDocument;

  _updateData() async {
    await db
        .collection('flutter_data2')
        .document(_currentDocument.documentID)
        .updateData({'title': _titleController.text});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('update'),
            ),
            body: _buildUpdate(context)));
  }

  // I wrapped the code in a streambuilder to give the RaisedButton a doc
  Widget _buildUpdate(BuildContext context) {
    final Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    //It consists of two textfields and raisedbuttons.
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: db.collection('flutter_data2').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return Column(
            children: snapshot.data.documents.map<Widget>((doc) {
              return Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                    child: Card(
                      elevation: 2.0,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0)),
                      child: Form(
                        key: _formKey,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12, right: 12),
                          child: Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              TextFormField(
                                controller: _titleController,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'title'),
                                validator: (String value) {
                                  if (value.isEmpty) {
                                    return 'title empty';
                                  } else {
                                    return null;
                                  }
                                },
                              ),
                              TextFormField(
                                controller: _titleController,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'desc'),
                                validator: (String value) {
                                  if (value.isEmpty) {
                                    return 'desc empty';
                                  } else {
                                    return null;
                                  }
                                },
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  RaisedButton(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)),
                    child: Text('update'),
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    onPressed: () async {
                      if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                        _updateData();
                        _titleController.text = doc.data[
                            'title']; //To write this code, I covered everything with a streambuilder.

                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              );
            }),
          );
        } else {
          return SizedBox(); 
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add `toList()` after mapping the documents.

Another way to deal with this is to use [collection for](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#lists) :

```
children: [
    for (final doc in snapshot.data.documents)
        Column(
            ...
        )
]
```